# Set the "Name" value of INSTALLDIR in wix

Tags: wix, installation, virtual-directory

I am creating installer for WCF service. The installer will take virtual directory name, domain name, username and password as input from user and will create app. pool with user identity and virtual directory in IIS. It also creates directory at C:\Intetpub\WWWRoot\ path. I want the name of that directory same as the name of virtual directory path but below code creates directory with the name "[WEB_APP_NAME]". I have gone through some threads which suggest that this can be done using custom action. I am pretty new in Wix and I don't know what changes I need to make in below code. Can someone please guide me..?
Below is my code:

```
<Fragment>
<?include ConfigurationInitialize.wxi ?>

<Property Id="IISROOT">
  <RegistrySearch Id="IISROOT"
                  Type="directory"
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="Software\Microsoft\InetStp"
                  Name="PathWWWRoot" />
</Property>

<!--<Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />-->
<!-- TODO: Put your code here. -->
<!-- The root of life for any installer. -->
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
  <!-- Install into the ISS root directory we found earlier. -->
  <Directory Id="IISROOT" Name='WebDir'>
    <!-- Here's this installers install location. -->
    <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR'
               Name='[WEB_APP_NAME]'>  <!-- THIS NAME SHOULD BE SAME AS THE NAME OF VIRTUAL DIRECTORY IN IIS-->
      <Directory Id='bin' Name='bin'></Directory>

      <!-- The component to define the Virtual Directory.-->
      <Component Id="WebVirtualDirComponent"
                 Guid="BE6C585A-9FB1-4109-86A4-4059F18F9C90">

        <util:User Id="MyWebAppPoolUser"
                       CreateUser="no"
                       Name="[WEB_APP_POOL_IDENTITY_NAME]"
                       Password="[WEB_APP_POOL_IDENTITY_PWD]"
                       Domain="[WEB_APP_POOL_IDENTITY_DOMAIN]" />

        <iis:WebAppPool Id="MyAppPool" Name="MyAppPool"
                        ManagedPipelineMode="Integrated" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" Identity="other" User="MyWebAppPoolUser" ></iis:WebAppPool>
        <!-- The virtual directory we are installing. -->
        <!-- The Alias attribute is the name thata will be put into IIS.-->
        <!-- The Directory attribute is the "Physical Path" property in 
              IIS and needs to tie to an ID specified in the setup. -->
        <!-- The WebSite attribute ties to a <WebSite> element in the 
             setup file. As this is an example of installing into the 
             "Default Web Site" that element is not under a component.-->
        <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VDir"
                           Alias="[WEB_APP_NAME]"
                           Directory="INSTALLDIR"
                           WebSite="DefaultWebSite">
          <!-- Turn the Virtual Directory into a web application. -->
          <iis:WebApplication Id="TestWebApplication"
                              Name="[WEB_APP_NAME]"
                              WebAppPool="MyAppPool"/>
        </iis:WebVirtualDir>
        <!-- This is pretty important. If the CreateFolder isn't there the 
             WebVirtualDir won't get created as there's no files in this 
             component. 
             http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03483.html -->
        <CreateFolder/>
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using custom actions?

You can use one of these custom action to change the property value during install:

1. a custom action which changes the directory property value scheduled before CostFinalize
2. a type 35 custom action which changes the directory path (should be scheduled after CostFinalize)

For example:

```
<CustomAction Id="ChangeDir" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[SomeValueorPropertyhere]"/>
```

2.Schedule the action during the InstallExecution phase (must be after the CostFinalize step):

```
<Custom Action="ChangeDir" After="CostFinalize"></Custom>
```

Comment: I tried the same. It gives me an error "could not access network location"